# Ukrainian language support in ConTeXt

Tags: context, languages, cyrillic

Are there any possibilities to write Ukrainian texts in the ConTeXt system?
What do I need to do this?

Comment: I don't know anything about ucraninan, but ConTeXt MkIV runs on LuaTeX so you don't need anything special, it recognises unicode characters.

Answer (score 3):

To change the labels for your figures, tables etc. use the `\mainlanguage` command, this will also load the right hyphenation patterns for the requested language.

You have to change also the font of your document, one font which has support for Cyrillics is Linux Libertine which can be loaded with `\setupbodyfont[libertine]` command.

```
\useMPlibrary[dum]

\mainlanguage[ukrainian] % \mainlanguage[ua]

\setupbodyfont[libertine]

\starttext

\completecontent

\completelistoffigures

\completelistoftables

\chapter{Figure label}

\startplacefigure[title={Dummy figure}]
    \externalfigure[width=8cm]
\stopplacefigure

\chapter{Table label}

\startplacetable[title={Dummy table}]
    \starttabulate[|l|pA{flushleft}|]
    \HL
    \NC \bf Knuth \NC \input knuth \NC\NR
    \HL
    \stoptabulate
\stopplacetable

\stoptext
```